# Программа дождь на с#

Tags: c#, winforms, анимация

### Преподаватель  дал задание написать программу на Windows-forms:

Создать приложение «Дождь», которое позволяет отображать на экране падающие капли дождя. Капля представляет собой набор графических элементов (по усмотрению программиста). Пользователь приложения должен установить параметры:
- скорость падения капель,
- минимальное и максимальное количество капель на экране, отображаемых одновременно.
При этом движение капель должно быть непрерывным

Так как с графикой и анимацией вообще нету опыта работы, решил обратиться сюда. С чего стоит начать? Может есть какие-то встроенные библиотеки/функции и тд? Или можете какие-то книги по работе с графикой посоветовать? Или онлайн источники?

Comment: Возьмите за основу вот этот [пример](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/9dbe8299-53ba-4954-9595-b38f573e4272/-windows-form?forum=forgamesru). Вместо звезд возьмите [символ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a7/index.htm) капли дождя. Шрифт используйте, например, "Segoe UI Emoji" - в нем есть этот символ. И чуть измените код: вместо случайного появления звезд сделайте движение капель сверху вниз. Делов на пять минут.

Comment: _есть какие-то встроенные библиотеки/функции ?_ - в WinForms основной способ работы с графикой класс [Graphics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.7.2). С помощью его методов рисуйте, что угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Задание не очень сложное (для меня).

**Простое решение:**

1. Создаешь класс капли (`Drop`) (контрол);
2. Создаешь цикл, в котором идет генерация и рендеринг капель (можно в отдельном потоке генерировать эти капли):

_

```
while (true)
{
    foreach (var drop in pictureBox.Drops)
    {
        // рендеринг капли
    }

    // рандомная генерация скорости, позиции, image'а и т.  д. для новых капель
}
```

3. Очищаешь `PictureBox`.

**Сложное решение**:
Сложное решение касается знаний ПООП (Паттерно-объектно-ориентированного проектирования) + знаний в работе Windows Froms + знаний в gemedev'е (рендеринг). Но если ты все это знаешь, то зачем ты задал этот вопрос?)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример реализации подобной штуки: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45144/Form-free-Desktop-Animation

В даном случае тебе нужно рисовать линии из пикселей которые бы ты рисовал под нужным направлением и с нужной длинной.

Если хочется больше красивостей, нужно будет нарисовать еще 2-5 анимаций стекающей капли по экрану и в рандомных местах экрана еще ее проигрывать.

Так же возможно тебе будет полезным погуглить `Particles System с# -unity` . Это система генерации частиц. Через нее тоже можно будет делать дождь